# Client/server architecture of data base systems

Tags: rdbms, rdbms-agnostic

What is meant by **client/server architecture** in fundamentals of **Database** systems?

I didn't get any proper answer from google.
It will be better for me if you provide some resources.

Answer (score 1):

Database architecture is logically divided into **two** types.

i. Logical two-tier Client / Server architecture

ii. Logical three-tier Client / Server architecture

**Two-tier Client / Server architecture** is used for User Interface program and Application Programs that runs on client side. An interface called ODBC(Open Database Connectivity) provides an API that allow client side program to call the dbms. Most DBMS vendors provide ODBC drivers. A client program may connect to several DBMS's. In this architecture some variation of client is also possible for example in some DBMS's more functionality is transferred to the client including data dictionary, optimization etc. Such clients are called **Data server**.

**Three-tier Client / Server database architecture** is commonly used architecture for web applications. Intermediate layer called Application server or Web Server stores the web connectivity software and the business logic(constraints) part of application used to access the right amount of data from the database server. This layer acts like medium for sending partially processed data between the database server and the client.

And what type of database you want to use is very important. Every Database architecture has some uniqueness and has some advantages. For more detail you can see these following links. May be that will help you more.

[computer notes site](http://ecomputernotes.com/computernetworkingnotes/network-technologies/what-is-client-server-architecture)

[Oracle site](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A57673_01/DOC/server/doc/SCN73/ch20.htm)

[this is more specific](http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/architecture-of-database)

[Pdf link](http://mazsola.iit.uni-miskolc.hu/tempus/discom/doc/db/tema02.pdf)